# getting html label text, converting to number, increment and then update label text with result

Tags: javascript, html, label, increment

I have a Label on my web page,

```
<label id="testLabelq" class="no_border" style="position: relative; top:-50px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0px; width:20%; height: 25px;">1</label>
```

which I want to get the number (initially 1) increment by one and then set the content of the label to the new value, on the press of this button.

```
<button id="testButtonplus" class="item_button" type="Button" style="position: relative; left:-40%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0px; width:20%; height: 50px;" onclick="add()">+</button>
```

my JavaScript function looks like this

```
        function add()
    {
            var quantity_temp = document.getElementById("testLabelq").innerText; 

            var qantity_int = parseInt(quantity_temp, 10) + 1;

            document.getElementById("testLabelq").innerHTML = "Test " + quantity_int.toString();
    }
```

the value of the label does not change when I press the button though...

if I change the line

```
document.getElementById("testLabelq").innerHTML = "Test " + quantity_int.toString();
```

to

```
document.getElementById("testLabelq").innerHTML = "Test " + quantity_temp;
```

then the label text updates with an extra "Test" on every button press.

therefore I think my number conversion must be at fault but I can't see where.

Thanks, 
Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work when simplified a bit:

```js
function add() {
  var quantity_temp = document.getElementById("testLabelq").innerText;
  var quantity_int = parseInt(quantity_temp, 10) + 1;
  document.getElementById("testLabelq").innerHTML = quantity_int.toString();
}
```

```html
<label id="testLabelq">1</label>
<button id="testButtonplus" class="item_button" type="Button" onclick="add()">+</button>
```

The one fix was a typo `qantity_int` should be `quantity_int`

Comment: Haha Thanks, I can't believe that, I fixed the typo and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in function (var `qantity_int =`) :

```
function add() {
    var quantity_temp = document.getElementById("testLabelq").innerText;
    var quantity_int = parseInt(quantity_temp, 10) + 1;
    document.getElementById("testLabelq").innerHTML = quantity_int.toString();
}
```